# convert image to colored LBP

Tags: python, opencv

I want to convert RGB image to colored local binary pattern. Here is code to convert grayscale image to LBP.

```
import cv2
import os
from skimage.feature import local_binary_pattern
import scipy.misc
im = cv2.imread('images/abc.jpg')
im_gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
radius = 3
no_points = 8 * radius
lbp = local_binary_pattern(im_gray, no_points, radius, method='uniform')
scipy.misc.imsave('lbp_images/abc.jpg', lbp)
```

But i want to convert colored image not grayscale.

Comment: What does your input image look like? And your output image? And the expected output image? Thank you.